# AWS CDK : how do I add a StringParameter as a secret to an ECS container?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm creating a StringParameter using AWS CDK :

```
cwa_config = ssm.StringParameter(
  self, name + "_ssm", string_value=json.dumps(cw_config_content)
)
```

How do I add this parameter to an ECS `ContainerDefinition` as a secret using AWS CDK?